# Algorithmic details behind Deep Feature Synthesis and Featuretools?

Tags: featuretools

In order to use properly, it is important to understand the algorithmic/mathematical basis for Deep Feature Synthesis and featuretools. Are there papers, patents, comparison with other tools?

Comment: essentially, just read the docs. It's no real myth what is happening there. You define relations between variables. According to those relationships variable combinations are constructed in a rather straight forward way.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the peer reviewed paper on Deep Feature Synthesis (the algorithm used in Featuretools) here: https://dai.lids.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/DSAA_DSM_2015.pdf.

The implementation has changed since publication, but the core ideas have not. Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.featuretools.com/) or [source on GitHub](https://github.com/featuretools/featuretools/) for the latest details.